# RegEx to validate worklog field pattern (to get how much time user worked on the task)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to build an HTML Form with an Input text field to hold users worklog hour. Where user can enter value something like:

> 1w 2d 4h 6m 5s

```
Where, 
w -> week
d -> day
h -> hour
m -> minute
5 -> second
```

User can enter anyone also or with combination of multiple (each separated by space).

On the server side I am able to parse the data to find worklog duration with any of input, if input is correct. But if it is wrong I want to provide client side validation...

Comment: How about just re-using your server-side validation? Apparently you already have code. Translating that to JavaScript probably isn't too hard. Also SO isn't a code-writing service. What have you tried and where are you stuck? As far as regexes go, this would be a fairly trivial one, so how are you arriving at a potential solution (regex) without actually knowing anything about it?

Comment: In server side I just written logic for parsing the data (if input is correct). So if it is wrong I am getting just an exception. For that purpose I want to impose client side validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for validating your space seperated input:

```
/^(?:\d+[wdhms](?: +|$))+$/gmi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tV1kN8/1)

It matches 1 or more set of text that starts with a number followed by any of the letters `[wdhms]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a simple regex like this :

```
\d+w \d+d \d+h \d+m \d+s
```

where \d+ means : 1 or N digits

If an input do not match this regex, the unput is a wrong input.

but 9999w 9999d 999999h 456489798m 154689789s will be a good input.

You need to be more specific on your demand and show what you have try already.

Comment: The anubhava's answers is better, i didn't read : "User can enter anyone also or with combination of multiple (each separated by space)."

Answer (score 1):

This regex will allow any of the values to be optional and accept a space between them:

```
^(\d+w)?(\s?\d+d)?(\s?\d+h)?(\s?\d+m)?(\s?\d+s)?$
```

If you need to enforce the space between values is present you will need to check against this regex in addition to the previous one:

```
^\d+[wdhms](\s\d+[wdhms])*$
```